# how can i efficiently model my Mongoose Schema's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Good Morning all! - i'll try to keep it short.

Coming from a begginers SQL/EF background i definitely went into mongoose with the wrong mindset.

I have 3 tables:

Users /
Boards /
BoardObjects

Now originally i thought about storing the boards as an array in the users document. But i think i'm approaching this wrong and i need community advice.

i need to be able to query what users what own what boards, and what objects are on those boards, and the arrays i put in were a nightmare. Then i thought, do i even need to cross these over?

for example, if i store a User, and then create a board, and in the board has a UserId that has to be unique to the user, and same for the BoardObjects, UserId and a BoardId, from what i've read so far seems it might be possible this way using joins and whatnot, which ive still got to learn..

Whats the community view here? do you embed or normalise often? or is this a valid way of managing related data in mongoose?

*Providing Boards model for context*

```
const Board = mongoose.model('Board', new mongoose.Schema({
    Ownerid: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    datecreated: {
        type: Date,
    },
    datemodified: {
        type: Date
    },
    BoardObjects: [{ boardobjectid: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BoardObject' } }],
}));
```

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am understanding you correctly, you need to create a relationship between the two tables.  in the user model you can add something like.

```
userSchema.virtual('boards', {
    ref: 'Boards',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner'
});
```

then as part of your boards model build your relationship with the user as an object on the model like this.

```
owner:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my knowledge,You can go with following answer as below:



 const Board= new mongoose.Schema({
    Ownerid: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        datecreated: {
            type: Date,
        },
        datemodified: {
            type: Date
        }
    })

    const Board=mongoose.model('Board',userSchema)
```

Comment: Sorry mate but you omitted BoardObjects entirely, and it doesnt really answer my question, you've just refactored the way the model is exported which was working fine as it was..

Nevertheless, thanks for your time though